# .js script file containing jquery not executing from master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 2 div tags in master page. When I move mouseover 1 div tag the other div tag should show. JQuery code is in .js file. When I put .js file in Content page jquery works fine. When I move the .js file to master page jquery code does not work. I need the jQuery to be in Master page because div tags needs to be accessed from all content pages.
I am new to jQuery, any help will be appreciated.

Code: 
jQuery code in .js file

```
$(function () {
    alert("Hello");
    $("nav").hide();
    $("#divSignAccount").mouseover(function () {
        $("nav").show();
    });
    $("nav").mouseover(function () {
            $("nav").show();
        });
    $("nav").mouseout(function () {
        $("nav").hide();
    });
});
```

Master Page  code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-

1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../Script/BookStore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">        

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body>    
    <form id="form1" runat="server">                      
        <!-- Header -->
        <header>
            <!-- Sign In dropdown -->
            <div id="divSignAccount" class="divSignIn">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlSignIn" runat="server" CssClass="displayText">Sign In</asp:HyperLink><br />
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlYourAccount" runat="server" CssClass="text">Your Account</asp:HyperLink><br />
            </div><br>            
        </header>     
        <nav>
            <div id="divDD">
                <div id="divSignNew">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSignIn" runat="server" Text="Sign in" CssClass="signInBtn" /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="New Customer?" CssClass="text"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlNew" runat="server" CssClass="text">Start Here</asp:HyperLink><br />
                </div>
                <div id="divUser">         
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlAccount" runat="server" CssClass="text">Your Account</asp:HyperLink><br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlOrders" runat="server" CssClass="text">Your Orders</asp:HyperLink><br />            
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlManageReview" runat="server" CssClass="text">Manage Reviews</asp:HyperLink><br />
                </div>
                <div id="divAdmin" runat="server">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlCategory" runat="server" CssClass="text">Category</asp:HyperLink><br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlBooks" runat="server" CssClass="text">Books</asp:HyperLink><br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlUOS" runat="server" CssClass="text">UserOrderStatus</asp:HyperLink><br />
                </div>
            </div>
       </nav> 

...
```

jQuery code does not fire.

If I place js script tag in content page jQuery code works.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Try to drag and drop your js in master and check if  path is as you define

Comment: I actually drag dropped js script file in master page. It didn't work.

Comment: Best Practice: Put your `scripts` at the end of Layout before closing `body` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Master Page head section type:

```
<script src='<%# ResolveUrl("~/Script/BookStore.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In Master page Page-Load event handler type this code:

```
Page.Header.DataBind();
```

This works.

Comment: Worked for me too. My issue was the content page loading scripts placed in the header, but not the master page. Doing exactly what you described here solved my issue, and now the scripts are executing from my master page.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this head in master. The position of my master is in the root. Javascript is in Scripts folder. I try your code and it's work. I try with "Applications Web Form ASP.NET" template visualstudio 2012

```
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Applicazione ASP.NET</title>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">        
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" /> 
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="Scripts/bookstore.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Thanks Diego for the code, but Master page is in Master folder. Sorry I forgot to mention, Master page is in Master folder, BookStore.js is in Script folder. I am using Visual Studio 2010. jQuery code does not work.

Comment: Thanks Diego - If I place Master Page in root folder it is able to access jQuery script file, but if I place Master Page in Master folder jQuery stops working.                                   Master Page needs to be in Master folder because all the other content pages are accessing it from Master folder. Hope the problem is clear. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Place your script in $(document).ready(function(){.... your script here ...});
So it is ruuned when the dom is ready

Comment: lalo- Thanks. $ is short for (document).ready function. This jQuery works fine from content page. It does not work from Master page.